# What's the best pattern for injecting a bean with arguments?

Tags: spring, grails, factory-pattern

I have a number of cases in my app where client code wants to create a bean on-demand. In each case, the bean has 1 or 2 constructor arguments which are specified by the client method, and the rest are autowired.

Ex:

```
//client code
MyQuery createQuery() {
    new MyQuery(getSession())
}

//bean class I want to create
//prototype scoped
class MyQuery {
    PersistenceSession session
    OtherBeanA a
    OtherBeanB b
    OtherBeanC c
}
```

I want A, B, and C to be autowired, but I have the requirement that 'session' has to be specified by the calling code. I want a factory interface like this:

```
interface QueryFactory {
    MyQuery getObject(PersistenceSession session)
}
```

What's the most efficient way to wire up the factory? Is it possible to avoid writing a custom factory class that does `new MyQuery(...)`? Can ServiceLocatorFactoryBean be used for something like this?

Comment: Did you find a way to accomplish the bean on-demand? I'm curious if my solution helped or if you used another method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, I'm troubleshooting a show-stopper issue on a different project, so I didn't get to try it yet. I'll check it out as soon as I can and let you know if it helps. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Autowired` annotation on your other beans and then use the `ApplicationContext` to register the new bean.  This assumes otherBeanA is an existing bean.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

class MyQuery {
    @Autowired  
    OtherBeanA otherBeanA

    PersistenceSession persistenceSession

    public MyQuery(PersistenceSession ps){
        this.persistenceSession = ps
    }
}
```

I'm not positive if this is the most efficient way to create a new bean, but it seems to be the best way at runtime.

```
import grails.util.Holders
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConstructorArgumentValues
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericBeanDefinition
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

class MyQueryFactory {
    private static final String BEAN_NAME = "myQuery"

    static MyQuery registerBean(PersistenceSession ps) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = Holders.getApplicationContext()

        def gbd = new GenericBeanDefinition(
                beanClass: ClientSpecific.MyQuery,
                scope: AbstractBeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE,
                autowireMode:AbstractBeanDefinition.AUTOWIRE_BY_NAME
            )

        def argumentValues = new ConstructorArgumentValues()
        argumentValues.addGenericArgumentValue(ps)
        gbd.setConstructorArgumentValues(argumentValues)

        ctx.registerBeanDefinition(BEAN_NAME, gbd)

        return ctx.getBean(BEAN_NAME)
    }
}
```

Instead of using `Holders`, it's advised to use the `ApplicationContext` from dependecy inject if available, you could then pass this to the `registerBean` method.

```
static MyQuery registerBeanWithContext(PersistenceSession ps, ApplicationContext ctx) {
    ...
}
```

Calling class:

```
def grailsApplication    
...
PersistenceSession ps = getRuntimePersistenceSession()

MyQueryFactory.registerBean(ps, grailsApplication.mainContext)
```

I changed the name of the method to truly reflect what it's doing - registering a spring bean as opposed to instantiating a `MyQuery`.  I pass back the bean using the `getBean` method, but you also have access to the same bean using the `ApplicationContext` once it's been created.

```
def myQueryBean = MyQueryFactory.registerBean(ps)
// or somewhere other than where the factory is used
def grailsApplication
def myQueryBean = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('myQuery')
```